# How can I resize the code completion bar in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

How do I make the code completion bar of Visual Studio smaller?
It's taking up the whole screen:
[image: It's taking up the whole screen]

I have tried researching this online and even asked everyone I know on discord. But nobody could answer to my question. I have heard that this was from the recent UI update.